# What does "湯冷ましを兼ねて" mean?

Tags: translation

While looking around, I found this [湯冷ましを兼ねて] expression that no dictionary has been able to translate.

Examples of use would be the [再び湯冷ましを兼ねて周辺を徘徊。] line in [this post](http://redsnowman.cocolog-nifty.com/urawa_goten/2009/07/post-a4f8.html) or the first sentence in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/nbcnbnc/status/295542916850524160), just picking up two random google results.

Answer (score 4):

[湯]{ゆ}[冷]{ざ}まし is one word. It means cooling down your body after taking a bath. In our culture, the bath tub is significantly important in daily life, compared with other countries. I think it's because of the damp weather in our archipelago.

When parents see their kids staying naked and watching TV after bath, especially in winter, they may say "湯冷めすると風邪をひくから、早く服を着なさい。". It means 'Wear something now because you will get a cold if you cool down too much."

This "冷まし" is attributive form of "冷ます", "冷め" is a nominalization of verb "冷める".

Both verbs mean cool down, but "冷ます" is transitive, and "冷める" is intransitive.

Good example is "[目]{め}[覚]{ざ}まし時計" = alarm clock (clock that *wakes* you), and "目覚め" = awakening (you *wake* up).

Comment: 例えば・・・「まわる」「さめる」「かたづく」「流れる」「いえる(癒える)」が自動詞で、「まわす」「さます」「かたづける」「流す」「いやす」が他動詞/causative verb で、「まわし」「さまし」「かたづけ」「流し」「いやし」がその名詞形/noun form ・・・とか？

Comment: Takeshinho's answer is not entirely correct. The meaning of 湯冷まし is correct, but the explanation of まし is not; rather we're dealing with a lexical causative. And 覚まし has only indirectly to do with 冷まし. The former means "wake up (transitive)", and the latter means "cool down (transitive)". The different kanji allude to the different meanings quite openly. Please also see my revised answer below.

Comment: Thanks Chocolate, I have missed the angle from trasitive and intransitive verbs. 湯冷まし is done with intentention to cool down, and 湯冷め happens if you let it. I will correct my answer

Comment: I don't see how Takeshinho's is an answer to the question "What does '湯冷ましを兼ねて' mean?" The expression in question doesn't even appear in Takeshinho's answer.

Comment: Thomas, I thought the word "湯冷まし" is not familiar with non-natives and it will be easier if it's meaning is clear. 〜を兼ねて can be seen in some textbook, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The expression ～を兼ねて means "combined with ～", or simply "with".

湯冷ましを兼ねて（何かをする・どこかへ行く）means "to do something/to go somewhere in order to cool down after a hot bath".
It has been questioned in comments to an earlier version of this answer whether the purposive interpretation of "in order to" is adequate. While I don't think that it would be adequate to translate every instance of を兼ねて as "in order to", it appears to me that in this instance, i.e. 湯冷ましを兼ねて, the action of cooling down after a bath is what one wants to primarily achieve. The action expressed by the matrix predicate is the one that one sees as suitable of achieving this purpose. The relationship between the two actions can then be expressed by purposive "in order to".

Comment: Those were just examples, and I'm interested in the meaning of the tweet. Or the mening it could have as a subordinate sentence or modifier (written before a person's name).

Comment: Where did you find the meaning "in order to" for を兼ねて? According to all my references this expression is just used (as you also say) to describe combining activities／functions, which is consistent with meaning of the kanji itself?